# Regular expression for numbers between 200 and 500 except 499

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression for numbers between 200 and 500 except 499, but I don't know how to make that exception. It is for it's a regular expression for fail2ban, can you help me?

Comment: Is this an exercise in using regexes, or might it make more sense to use an `if` statement in your language of choice using numerical comparison operators?

Comment: I don't have much experience in stackoverflow, it's a regular expression for fail2ban, I guess it will be evaluated in the same way as it would be in a bash script.

Comment: @jsheeran it was to fail2ban, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/[23][0-9]{2}|4[0-8][0-9]|49[0-8]|500/
```

If RegExp is what you want, this would be it. If you give us more context, maybe there are better ways for this check.

Another alternative is to explicitly exclude 499 as a match:

```
/(?!499)[2-4][0-9]{2}|500/
```